# Make files uploaded by vsftpd automatically inherit owner from parent directory

Tags: permissions, vsftpd

I am running a vsftpd server with a few user accounts. Every user has his own, private directory set as chroot in which no one but he himself should write, like this:

ftphomes/
userdir1
userdir2
userdir3
...

So far this works, every file uploaded into these directories has the owner user:usergroup

However, I have  a public directory (mounted into each userdir with mount --bind) in which everyone should have write permissions for everyones files. I created a group called ftpusergrop containing every user from the FTP server.

My goal is to set the owner of each file in the public directory to user:ftpusergroup and the permissions 774.
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Let me get you, user ==> user, group ==> ftpusergroup. or your after just the group part?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to look at the SETGID bit? It keeps the group owning the permission when a user creates a new file inside it. Does this answer look helpful?: https://serverfault.com/questions/306253/groups-and-owners-with-ftp?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Set up the ownership with:

```
sudo chown -R user:ftpusergroup /path/to/public_folder
```

Using `sefacl` set the permission bit:

```
sudo setfacl -R -d -m u:user:rwx,g:ftpusergroup:rwx,o::r /path/to/public_folder
```

Information:

`-R`: recursively

`-d`: set as default for future folders and files

`-m`: modify existing file access control settings

Source:

`man setfacl`